# How to make openInfoWindowHtml work in Google Maps 2

Tags: google-maps, extjs, extjs4, google-maps-api-2

I'm setting up a extjs panel with a GMap2 embedded.  Here's the setup:

```
 map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("gmappanel"));
 map.setCenter(new GLatLng(58.019257, -115.572402), 3);
 map.setUIToDefault();
```

I'm using the example from [here](http://sub1.econym.org.uk/gmap/elabel.htm) so that when I click a marker, I get an info window.  The problem is, the event fires and I can see the proper HTML in the console, but nothing else happens.  The info window simply doesn't open.  no error, nothing.

Here's the code for that:

```
 function createMarker(point, val) {
    var marker = new GMarker(point);
    var name = val.data.name;
    var html = "<table class='marker'>";
    html += "<tr><td>Name: </td><td>" + name + "</td></tr>";
    html += "</table>";

    GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
        debug("Marker fired");
    });

    return marker;
}
```

Here's how I call it:

```
 var marker = createMarker(point,store.getAt(i));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: At some point after calling createMarker, I imagine you add it to the map with a map.addOverlay(marker)?

Comment: Yes I do.  The marker appears, but the event doesn't fire.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your HTML is not valid.  Can you dump some example html data that you are passing to the openInfoWindowHtml?  Your createMarker function works just fine with :

```
var html = "<table class='marker'><tr><td>Name: </td><td> sometext </td></tr></table>";
```

what version of the api are you using? 2.x?

Comment: The HTML is definitely valid.  I even tried simply passing in a string.  I'm using 2.X.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you want [bindInfoWindowHtml](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMarker.bindInfoWindowHtml), not [openInfoWindowHtml](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMarker.openInfoWindowHtml).

Something along the lines of..

```
function createMarker(point, val) {
    var marker = new GMarker(point);
    var name = val.data.name;
    var html = "<table class='marker'>";
    html += "<tr><td>Name: </td><td>" + name + "</td></tr>";
    html += "</table>";
    marker.bindInfoWindowHtml(html);
    return marker;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You also have two marker variables defined in different scopes, check to make sure you have the listener on the right "marker".